# Bat files - Adding a single "double" quote to a search string

Tags: batch-file

Yet another bat file question.

I have a bat file that calls an internal routine. It calls it like this:

```
call :isRunning %parentCntr% %replStr% || call :startRunning %parentCntr% %replBat%
```

I need to append a single double quote to the end of the %parentCntr% variable as my subroutine does a wmic search for 'Thread=1' (where 1 is the value of parentCntr) and is getting a false positive when it "sees" 'Thread=11'. In this particular case, I need to make the search string 'Thread=1"' or 'Thread=11"'.

I have tried to use a quote and an escaped quote but to no avail. Before I start deconstructing the batch file can any one suggest how I can achieve this?

Addendum.

I removed and changed the original question because it was based on a false premise. The subroutine originally posted is used for two different purposes so I need to be able to pass in two different strings.

The real question here is "how do I append a single double quote to the value of a variable?".

The earlier post was noise and should be disregarded. Everything else is working perfectly.

Comment: It would certainly help if you tell us how `%tgtString%` was defined, and its value string. It would also help if you show us how you are passing the arguments `%1` and `%2`, and what their value strings are. Then we need to know why you are using `name like '_progres.exe'` as opposed to `Name='_progres.exe'` and if there's a good reason for it, what the names are, you are trying to match. We need you to submit enough information for us to reproduce your methodology, environment, input, expectations, and actual results; not just some code.

Comment: Now you have removed/replaced the code too, we have even less information. Please read [mcve], and make some much needed edits.

Comment: `wmic process` for me does not produce a string `Thread=1`. Please post a relevant portion of the two lines `Thread=1` and `Thread=11` so we can fix your now-deleted `findstr` command.